# Abbyy and Informatica How do i manually run a file

Tags: etl, informatica, abbyy

**How do i run a file of images in Informatica manually**? My company has run several images in informatica with Abbyy that does data transformation, but however there were some images with text's, but texts were not produced.. Therefore, **i am asked to run new images in Abbyy Informatica, to reproduce those errors**, where some images did not produce texts. Please give me some guidance

I am still a student interning at the company..

Comment: Is this what you're using?: https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/informatica_ocr_plugin

Comment: @Maciejg Hi Yes i am currently using that plug in. Which is why I don't quite understand how to run images manually.. Please assist me on this! Thank you kind person!

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Hi, I think i am using Abbyy Transformation. Or doing a language transform. As what my colleague said before he left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the following [plugin](https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/informatica_ocr_plugin), please see the video.

Now, if by "How do i run a file of images in Informatica manually?" you mean that the problem you have is with executing the workflow for a given sest of image files, then you need to perform an `indirect load`. Please google that. This is mentioned in the video and it simply means that as a source you need to use a file that contains a list of files to be processed. And on the Session you need to set the Souce Qualifier property `Source filetype` to `Indirect`.

Comment: Hi Maciejg, Sorry to ask more, that video plug in is using Linux, however i had just found out that my server is using Windows OS. Does the video still apply to me? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, at least as far as Informatica is involved there should be no difference.